# malloc() causing exc_bad_access when inserting a new node in linked list in xcode

Tags: c, xcode, linked-list, exc-bad-access

I am writing linked list in Xcode in C.
in fact I can append the first node to the list. And everything runs well.
However when I append the second to the list, Xcode shows me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line of malloc() a new node.
I know this error caused by accessing NULL pointer, but I cannot find where is wrong.
Here is part of my code.

SinglyLinkedList.c:

```
void llist_node_append(SList *ptr, const void *datap)
{
    struct llist *me = ptr;
    struct node *newnodep;

    newnodep = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (newnodep == NULL)
        FatalError("No space to append new node.\n");
    newnodep->datap = malloc(sizeof(me->elemsize));
    if (newnodep->datap == NULL)
        FatalError("No space to append new node.\n");

    memcpy(newnodep->datap, datap, me->elemsize);

    newnodep->next = NULL;
    me->last->next = newnodep;
    me->last = newnodep;
    if (llist_is_empty(me))
        me->head->next = newnodep;
}

void llist_travel(SList *ptr, node_proc_fun_t *proc)
{
    struct llist *me = ptr;
    struct node *curr;
    for (curr = me->head.next; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        proc(curr->datap);
    }
}
```

main.c:

```
struct node {
    void *datap;
    struct node *next;
};

struct llist {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *last;
    int elemsize;
};

typedef struct food_list {
    char breakfast[20];
    char lunch[20];
    char dinner[20];
} FoodList;

void llist_print(void* elem)
{
    FoodList *temp = elem;
    printf("the breakfast is %s\nthe lunch is %s\nthe dinner is %s\n", temp->breakfast, temp->lunch, temp->dinner);
}

int main()
{
    SList list = *llist_new(sizeof(FoodList));

    FoodList UCSB = {
        "milk and bread",
        "beef",
        "burger",
    };

    FoodList UCB = {
        "apple",
        "juice",
        "eggs",
    };

    llist_node_append(&list, &UCSB);
    llist_node_append(&list, &UCB);
    llist_travel(&list, llist_print);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(me->elemsize));`  should simply be `malloc(me->elemsize);` in your data item allocation. That was the first thing I noticed.

Comment: That's probably the issue. `sizeof(me->elemsize)` is simply `sizeof(int)` (either 4 or 8), so you're allocating far too little space and overrunning it with your `memcpy()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! This is exactly the problem. And now I can append nodes as many as I want. I have spent more than two hours on this sizeof().

Comment: @duskwuff. yes it is. And now everything runs well. In fact I drew

Comment: @duskwuff. yes it is. And now everything runs well. In fact I drew many pictures to find out if I connect wrong pointer.